# How to limit selected items that appear on special page

Tags: craft3

I have a client that wants to select "featured" entries to appear on their home page, and in a specific order that they can set and change. My initial idea was to set up a featured check box and just search for that, but I need to limit the possible number of total entries selected to 5.

The entires come from multiple sections so I cannot just limit one section, and I need to limit how many they can select on the backend, not just how many appear in the view (that I can do).

right now the set up is with the featured checkbox, but the problem is they can just keep checking boxes and if they do not uncheck another one it will not have the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an [Entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/entries-fields) to the home page Single and limit it to 5? That also allows designated users to decide what appears on the home page.

Comment: then they have to enter the same content in twice.

Comment: Not sure if I follow that one. They create several entries. Using the Entries Field on the home page they just select which ones they want to show (and in which order)?

Comment: But they want to grab these entries from other sections and assign them as featured so they appear on the home page.  So an entry from the news section, and an entry from the explore section, etc.  They are entries that are from different parts of the site.

Comment: Perfectly possible using the Entries Field. See the link to the docs in my original reply. Just create a "Featured Entries" field and include all sections in the settings, add it to the Home Page's form layout and use that field in the home page template.

Comment: Wow I was making that so hard and didn't even need to, thanks!